# FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.
В примерах  [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)   и [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) от google используют однотипные фрагменты и метод getItem реализован с помощью newInstance

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
```

но что делать когда фрагменты разные ? первая мысль передавать в адаптер коллекцию фрагментов и сделать примерно так

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }
```

насколько это оправдано? - встречал негативное мнение по схожей реализации, как лучше реализовывать такие вещи?
спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекоммендую прочесть:

http://android-helper.com.ua/swipe-tabs/

И еще

http://android-helper.com.ua/pagertabstrip/

Доходчево написанно!

Answer (score 2):

В общем-то, по своему опыту разбора данного вопроса, пришел к выводу, что нужно делать примерно так:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        fragment=Fragment.instantiate(context, MyClass1.class.getName());
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment=Fragment.instantiate(context, MyClass2.class.getName());
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Практика подтверждает, все работает как надо. Тем не менее, допускаю, что кто-то подскажет какое-то более оптимальное решение.